# Pyinstaller fails to find packages when using onefile

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make an .exe from a python script, using pyinstaller, but having issues when trying to make as onefile.

When running just below, everything works fine

```
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

When trying to make onefile, it cannot find packages.

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

When running the resulting .exe, I see errors such as: **No module named 'mylib'**

Trying to explicitly include doesn't work either.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hiden-import=mylib myscript.py
```

**You can reproduce using the example below:**

My file structure is exactly this:

```
__init__.py
myscript.py
Compile.bat
.\mylib
--| __init__.py
--| mypackage.py
```

myscript.py:

```
from mylib.mypackage import myfunc

x = myfunc()
```

mypackage.py:

```
def myfunc():
input('Successfully Run')
```

Compile.bat:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
set library="mylib"
set libdest="dist\mylib"
robocopy "%library%" "%libdest%" /E
```

All **init** files are empty.

After running the batch file, the dist folder structure is:

```
.\dist
--| myscript.exe
--| .\mylib
------| __init__.py
------| mypackage.py
```

Any suggestions or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @john-hen You're right.  Copying the files was acting as a work-around only for the normal method without onefile.  I thought that was always required, and it's not.  Your comments helped me look in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

Leaving the `__init__.py` file in the root messes with `pyinstaller` in some way.

When using a normal build, copying the package into the folder is a work around.  This made me think it was normally required, but it's not.

When using `--onefile`, copying the packages into the folder does not act as a work around for some reason.

Resolved folder structure:

```
myscript.py
Compile.bat
.\mylib
--| __init__.py
--| mypackage.py
```

And the batch no longer needs any copies.

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```